# Simple div hide or show based on menu selection

Tags: jquery, html, menu, selection, onchange

This should be easy...but I have spent the better part of the day trying to figure it out.  Using jQuery: The code is like this:

```
<tr> 
  <select name="exist_author" class="exist_author">     
     <option value="select">Select</option>
     <option value="new_auth">I cant find my author</option>
     <option value="2">Tom Wolf</option>
     <option value="1">Frank Baum</option> 
  </select>
</tr>       

<script type="text/javascript">         
  $(document).ready(function(){             
     $("#new_author").css("display","none");             
     $(".exist_author").change(function(){
         var test = $(this).val();
         if(test !== 'new_auth') {
            $("#new_author").fadeOut("slow");       
         } 

         else {
            $("#new_author").fadeIn("slow");        
         }
     });
  });
</script>

<tr id="new_author">Text to Show on 'I cant find my author' menu selection</tr>
```

I have gotten the fade in to work on the selection, but it immediately fades back out.

Comment: We need to see what your markup looks like.

Comment: I've tried you js script and it works just fine. Maybe indeed you have some layout issues.

Comment: I apologize...first time post.  The formatting was terrible.  I have revised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like fading a TR isn't supported, try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
  $(document).ready(function(){             
     $("#new_author").css("display","none");             
     $(".exist_author").change(function(){
         var test = $(this).val();
         if(test !== 'new_auth') {
            $("#new_author").fadeOut("slow");       
         } 

         else {
            $("#new_author").fadeIn("slow");        
         }
     });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td>
  <select name="exist_author" class="exist_author">     
     <option value="select">Select</option>
     <option value="new_auth">I cant find my author</option>
     <option value="2">Tom Wolf</option>
     <option value="1">Frank Baum</option> 
  </select>
</td><td>
<table>
<tr ><td id="new_author" style="color:red">this one</td></tr>
<tr id="test1"><td>content</td></tr>
<tr id="test2"><td>content</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're omitting td tags for the sake of simplicity, otherwise it's simply not a valid html. And I really don't understand why you need to use a table at all instead of divs.

Anyway, within your td tag that has to show text, put that text in a div, and giv it an id "new_author" (remove that id from tr tag).

Also, don't put script between the tr tags. Either put it in the head section or right before closing body tag.

Comment: Problem solved.  The select class "exist_author" was also the class of the parent <td> tag.  That is what was causing the thing to appear and disappear immediately after.  Thanks so much for your help guys!